# What constitutes a "compatible shape" for array arguments to J verbs?

Tags: arrays, arguments, j

I'm in the process of learning (and having my mind blown by) J, and reading *Learning J*. I have noticed that many (all?) verbs I've been learning are pretty flexible with their arguments. I can do the traditional `4 - 2`, or I can use it with lists e.g. `4 5 - 3 4`, and can even do `3 4 5 - 1` which seems to "promote" the right-hand side of the operator to an array even though I just gave it a scalar.

I assume the latter behavior is covered by this line, from ch. 2 of the aforementioned text:

> Consequently, the two arguments of = must have the same shapes, (or at
>   least, as in the example of Y=2, compatible shapes). Otherwise an
>   error results.

Indeed, `3 4 5 - 2 3` is an error. What is the technical definition of a "compatible shape"? Is it as simple as "same shape or a scalar", or is there more to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Dictionary page [B. Verbs](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/dictionary/dictb.htm) :

> Agreement. In the phrase `p v q`, the arguments of `v` must agree in the
>   sense that one frame must be a prefix of the other

So the following will all work

```
  (i. 2 3) * (i. 2 3 4)     NB. frame of left arg is prefix of the right arg
  (i. 2) * (i. 2 3 4)       NB. frame of left arg is prefix of the right arg
  (i. 2 3 4) * (i. 2 3)     NB. frame of right arg is prefix of the left arg
```

For a formal definition of *frame* see the Dictionary page [A. Nouns](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/dictionary/dicta.htm)

I'd recommend [this section of J for C programmers](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/jforc/loopless_code_i_verbs_have_r.htm#_Toc191734332) as a thorough coverage of these concepts.